# Error using plotly from R from Windows command line

Tags: r, windows, command-line, plotly

I am using `plotly` in a project being used/run from windows/linux/mac machines. Generally this has been working fine, but I have an issue when trying to generate `plotly` plots from **command line** in **windows**.

As a reproducible example, following the code [here](https://plot.ly/r/getting-started/):

```
install.packages("plotly")
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "box")
p
```

Results in the error:

`Error in shell.exec(url) :
   access to '...\Local\Temp\Rtmpq42cvu\viewhtmla386dc27ae4/index.html' denied`

That last backslash being the wrong way is an obvious candidate for the problem. And if I point my browser to the same file but with the last backslash changed to match the others, I see the plot as expected.

Could someone please check if they have the same problem? Note that I only have this problem when running from the **command line**. If I run the same code from Rstudio it works no problem. I'm on `R version 3.4.0` and `packageVersion("plotly")` returns `‘4.6.0’`.

Comment: Works for me on Windows 10 with Chrome - brings up Chrome to show the plotly plot. Guessing that it starts a browser, and that browser can't get to that file because of a security setting. Try copying that `index.html` file to your local directory and call it directly (which should also trigger the default browser). Does that work?

Comment: Thanks for checking. I can open the `.html` file where it is, but I have to adjust the url so that the last back-slash is the right way round (i.e. matches other slashes in the url). Just to double check yours is working from `cmd` command line in Windows 10?

Comment: Ah, Chrome was the answer. It seems Chrome is able to fix the offending slash silently. Setting my default browser to Chrome fixes/avoids this error. I have been avoiding the switch from Firefox, but it might be time. Although the issue might stem from the fact I'm using an old version of firefox (it's a University-managed PC and I'm unable to update).

Comment: YOu should put the solution into an answer, rather than editing your question. As a bonus, that means people can also upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comment from @MikeWise (many thanks) I tried switching my default browser from firefox to chrome, and this fixed the issue.

Also, I have confirmed that this issue is also resolved by using an up-to-date version of firefox.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark this correct  (you can't do it right away, have to wait some period of time).